# Are serial fields in NEW variable inside a before insert trigger function in postgresql initialized?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

In PostgreSQL 9.1, I need to assign another field in a table with the same value of the ID column which is `serial`.

For now I'm adding a `RETURNING` part to `INSERT` command and use a successive `UPDATE` command to update the record in the same transaction.

I'd really like to perform this operation in the same transaction and preferably same SQL command (without the need to resort to after insert triggers).

My question is inside the before insert trigger on the same table, is the `NEW` variable which is supposed to contain the record which is about to be inserted, already initialized with the return value of `nextval('seq_table')` for the `id` field or not?

Can I assign this value to another field in the same trigger function? is this valid?

```
NEW.custom_field := NEW.id;
```

Comment: "*I need to assign another field in a table with the same value of the ID column*" - Why do you think you "need" to do that? You are duplicating the data without any apparent reason. You can always write a view that will simply return that `id` value twice under two different names.

Comment: I need to be sure when dumping and restoring this table contents, while `id` field might be recomputed (and changed considering sequence types are not gapless), the *custom_filed* value stay the same. basically it should be a unique identifier for this record not only on this DB, but also on other systems which depend on it. I know I could use a UUID, but that's how things work for now.

Comment: A dump and restore (assuming you are talking about `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`) will - by definition - preserve the `id` values. Everything else would render those tools useless.

Comment: I tend to not think of id field as actual data, and I ignore them wherever I can (including in data dumps). Also the ORM framework I'm using doesn't allow access to id field as an implementation detail. So I had to create another field to mirror that.

Comment: I wonder what keeps you from just trying it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c91b7/1

Comment: I can try it, but I was looking for a confirmation from another dev or a reference to postgres docs confirming it (which I couldn't find).